# Upper bound of stopped Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, stopping-times

Let $\{B_t\}_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and $T$ be arbitrary stopping time, is it true that $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{1\wedge T}|]\leq C\cdot P(T<\infty)$ for some constant $C$? Here $C$ should be a universal constant over all stopping time $T$.

---

I can obtain the upper bound $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{1\wedge T}|]\leq 2\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|]\triangleq M < \infty$ because $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|$ is integrable. However, I am not sure how to make the upper bound involving $P(T<\infty)$ since on $\{T=\infty\}$, we have $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{1\wedge T}|]=0$.

Comment: Consider a special stopping time $T\equiv 0.5$, then $P(\{T<\infty\}\cap \{|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|>C\}) = P(|B_1-B_{0.5}|>C)$. For any $C$ it is positive, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless mistaken on the event $T\geq 1$, we have $|B_1-B_{1\wedge T}|=0$, so we get  $|B_1-B_{1\wedge T}|\leq 2.\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|$ so that :

$$\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{1\wedge T}|]=\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{1\wedge T}|.1_{T\leq 1}]$$
From Cauchy-Schwartz inequality we get :
$$\leq  2.\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|^2]^{1/2} P(T<1)^{1/2}\leq 2.\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|^2]^{1/2} P(T<+\infty)^{1/2}$$

This is not far but not what you are looking for.

So here is another try supposing that $T$ follows law $\mathbb P_T(u)$. We can write :
$$\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{1\wedge T}|]=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^\infty|B_1-B_{1\wedge u}|d\mathbb P_T(u)]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^1|B_1-B_{u}|d\mathbb P_T(u)]$$
$$=\int_0^1\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{u}|]d\mathbb P_T(u)$$
$$\leq \sup_{t\in [0,1]}\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{u}|]\int_0^1 d\mathbb P_T(u)$$
$$= \sup_{t\in [0,1]}\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{u}|]\mathbb P(T\leq 1)$$
$$\leq \sup_{t\in [0,1]}\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{u}|]\mathbb P(T< \infty)$$

Looks better now right ?

Comment: I don't understand why $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|1_{T\leq 1}] \leq \mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|]P(T<1)$. Are you using these two random variables are independent? Why are they independent?

Comment: You are irght I withdraw the answer until I investigate this point further

Comment: Correction done

Comment: Why is $P(T<1)^{1/2} \leq P(T<1)$?

Comment: Not my best day

Comment: Another try for this problem

Comment: Many Thanks! This new one looks nicer. My only fear is that the first equality may not be rigorous? I am not sure, but is it using marginal distribution or joint distribution?

Comment: Well $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{u}|]$ is just a (continuous) function of $u$ so taking the sup seems legit to me.

Comment: No I mean the equality $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{1\wedge T}|]=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^\infty|B_1-B_{1\wedge u}|d\mathbb P_T(u)]$.

Comment: No problem this is legit